# Need help with a limit to infinity involving a radical with indeterminate form (stuck in the factoring)

Tags: calculus, factoring, radicals, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

this is my first time on Math Exchange, I searched around the site and could not find a question for this math problem so I do not believe that I am asking a previously asked question, if I am please let me know....any way onto the question. (I apologize if the post is long, please let me know if posts should be shorter)

---

Ok so I am currently taking Calculus I and we were given a review sheet for our first exam, I was able to figure out pretty much all of the questions on it save this one I am about to show you. I understand how to solve the question, but I keep getting stuck on the factoring think any of you can show me where I am going wrong and what I should do so solve it? (By the way we are not allowed to use l'hospital's rule or this would be too simple)

---

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}
\sqrt{4x^6+7x^3+5}-2x^3
$$
Basically by looking at it I knew that this was going to be in an indeterminate form of 
$$
\infty-\infty
$$
So I began factoring:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} = \sqrt{4x^6+7x^3+5}-2x^3 * \qquad \frac{\sqrt{4x^6+7x^3+5}+2x^3}{\sqrt{4x^6+7x^3+5}+2x^3}
\\= \qquad \frac{4x^6+7x^3+5-4x^6}{\sqrt{4x^6+7x^3+5}+2x^3}=\qquad \frac{7x^3+5}{\sqrt{4x^6+7x^3+5}+2x^3}
$$
Kinda got stuck there....so can anyone be of help to me? It would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT: Thank you everybody for the quick replies and help, dividing what was left by x^3 put me on the right track to getting all of your answers of 7/4. Thank you much!

Comment: Try dividing top and bottom by $x^3$.

Comment: Trying that now....hope that works. :)

Edit: Yeah that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you multiply numerator and denominator by $1/x^3$ you will get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{7+5/x^3\over\sqrt{4+7/x^3+5/x^6}+2}=\frac 7{\sqrt4+2}=\frac74.$$

Comment: Ah thanks, for some reason I had though about dividing by x^3 but didn't think that would work, will try that now and see if I get the same results as you!

Edit: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing 
$$
\sqrt{4x^{6}+7x^{3}+5} = x^{3}\sqrt{4+7x^{-3}+5x^{-6}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can use the Taylor series for $\sqrt{1+u}=1+\frac{u}{2}+O(u^2)$. Then we compute:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{4x^6+7x^3+5}&=2x^3\sqrt{1+\frac{7x^3+5}{4x^6}}\\
&=2x^3\left(1+\frac{7x^3+5}{8x^6}+O(x^{-6})\right)\\
&=2x^3+\frac{7}{4}+O(x^{-3}).
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{4x^6+7x^3+5}-2x^3=\frac{7}{4}$.

Comment: While you're answer is perfectly correct, you should consider the OP's background when answering this. It's unlikely that a Calc I student is familiar with big-oh notation. In fact, he/she may not even be acquainted with Taylor series yet.

Comment: Never hurts to show multiple approaches, which may be helpful down the road.

Comment: I agree. Kindly consider that the OP may require some explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! It's true I haven't seen um... Big O notation before, but it seems interesting and may be something I review just to find out how it works 